# Support for norwegian characters in FPDF

Tags: php, linux, fpdf

I'm using fpdf to create some pdf's from a HTML-form.

Everything is working fine apart from the norwegian characters ÆØÅ doesn't work. They simply don't show. Because I am making this for norwegians, those characters are very important to make it useful.

How can I add support for ÆØÅ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try [iconv](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php):

Standard FPDF fonts use ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252. You can try iconv to  change character encoding.

```
Example:
     $str = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $str);
```

And if you can change your PDF generation code then please look at [mpdf](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/examples) : [UTF-8 multilingual](http://mpdf1.com/examples/example_utf8.pdf)

Hope this help!